# How can I make a JS string have newlines instead of showing \n?

Tags: javascript, database, string

How can I make it so that a JavaScript string makes a new line instead of showing \n? Say I have a string that goes:
I
Love
JS!

but when I show it again it shows:
I\nLove\nJS!

How can I make it do a newline??

(for context, im making a sync notepad that syncs every second and it saves it to a db and the db turns it into a string and stores it, but when I get it back the newlines just turn into \n's)

Comment: Fix whatever is causing it to become a literal `"\n"` in the first place, don't just patch the result.

Comment: What does "makes a new line" mean? New line where? In HTML?

Comment: How is your string being displayed? In HTML? An alert?

Comment: the string gets added into the value of a textbox and displays it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are rendering the string as HTML, the line-feeds will be preserved and should not be rendered.

If you are setting the HTML content of an element, you must convert them to line-breaks, unless you specify `white-space: pre`.

```js
const ref = sel => document.querySelector(sel); // Convenience function

const str = 'I\nLove\nJS!';

ref('.test-textarea-value').value = str;
ref('.test-html-pre').textContent = str;
ref('.test-html-split').innerHTML = str.split('\n').join('<br>');
ref('.test-html-replace').innerHTML = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

console.log(str);
alert(str);
```

```css
.test-html-pre { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<textarea rows="3" class="test-textarea-value"></textarea>
<p class="test-html-pre"></p>
<p class="test-html-split"></p>
<p class="test-html-replace"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It turns out I was using JSON.stringify() on the string the db returned? Removing that and using the example you gave me worked, thank you! ^^